# Computer don't detect android one usb device

Tags: usb, android

I have Ubuntu 14.04 installed on my system.

Right now I want to use an Android one device which is running `android 5.1` for testing purposes but the system can't detect the USB device. I followed some tutorials for setting `udev android rules files` but that wasn't able to solve my problem either.

Is there a problem with oem usb driver or something else? Same device easily detected on my other system which also runs Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: @PrashantChikhalkar: Could you please review my [edits](http://askubuntu.com/posts/659679/revisions) as this is the kind of work we're expecting from editors?  Formatting and tags are very low on the list of improvements. Spelling&Grammar first, then readability (which includes formatting), then tags.

Answer (score 0):

This fix worked with my android phone,

```
sudo apt-get install mtpfs
```

Once that's installed, plug in the phone to your computer.

If nothing happens, on the phone go to **Settings > Storage > Upper Right Corner > USB Computer Connection > Media Device**